# How could I host razor components in IIS?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, razor-components

I am setting up a razor components .net core 3.0 preview in IIS.
From VS 2019 via IIS Express site works fine, but when I am hosting it with IIS itself - front-end logic is not working (no click responses, etc) How can I host razor components in IIS?

As I am seeing from IIS Express panel - it is hosted on 2 ports while my app is working. (Probably, client and server side)
According to [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/razor-components/?view=aspnetcore-3.0) the app is included with the ASP.NET Core app in the published output.

My web.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\BlazorApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Looks like I am hosting only one side of razor components app, but should host both.

Comment: What version of IIS/Windows Server are you running? Razor components depend on SignalR (web sockets), which is only supported in IIS 8.0+ (Windows Server 2012+)

Comment: Windows 10 v.1809 with IIS 10.0. The same machine already hosts ASP.NET Core Web Api with SignalR Core inside.

Comment: Current preview3 only works with real websockets which is an optional feature which has to be enabled in IIS. Your other app may work because SignalR has fallback to long polling http requests when websockets don't work but that fallback is broken in preview3: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8384